# Predict in workflow throws that column doesn't exist

Tags: r, tidymodels

Given the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tidymodels)
library(ranger)

df <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/norhther/datasets/main/bitcoin.csv")

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date),
         Change_Percent = str_replace(Change_Percent, "%", ""),
         Change_Percent = as.double(Change_Percent)
         ) %>%
  filter(year(Date) > 2017)

int <- interval(ymd("2020-01-20"), 
                ymd("2022-01-15"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(covid = ifelse(Date %within% int, T, F))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Price, color = covid)) + 
    geom_line()

df <- df %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(lag1 = lag(Price),
         lag2 = lag(lag1),
         lag3 = lag(lag2),
         profit_next_day = lead(Profit))

# modelatge
df_mod <- df %>%
  select(-covid, -Date, -Vol_K, -Profit) %>%
  mutate(profit_next_day = as.factor(profit_next_day))

set.seed(42)
data_split <- initial_split(df_mod) # 3/4
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)

bitcoin_rec <- 
  recipe(profit_next_day ~ ., data = train_data) %>%
  step_naomit(all_outcomes(), all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

bitcoin_prep <-
  prep(bitcoin_rec)

bitcoin_train <- juice(bitcoin_prep)
bitcoin_test  <- bake(bitcoin_prep, test_data)

rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest(trees = 200) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

bitcoin_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(bitcoin_prep)

bitcoin_fit <-
  bitcoin_wflow %>%
  fit(data = train_data)

final_model <- last_fit(bitcoin_wflow, data_split)

collect_metrics(final_model)

final_model %>%
  extract_workflow() %>%
  predict(test_data)
```

The last chunk of code that extracts the workflow and predicts the `test_data` is throwing the error:

> Error in `stop_subscript()`: ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Column `profit_next_day` doesn't exist.

but `profit_next_day` exists already in `test_data`, as I checked multiple times, so I don't know what is happening. Never had this error before working with `tidymodels`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here comes from using `step_naomit()` on the outcome. In general, steps that change *rows* (such as removing them) can be pretty tricky when it comes time to resample or predict on new data. You can [read more in detail in our book](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#skip-equals-true), but I would suggest that you remove `step_naomit()` altogether from your recipe and change your earlier code to:

```r
df_mod <- df %>%
  select(-covid, -Date, -Vol_K, -Profit) %>%
  mutate(profit_next_day = as.factor(profit_next_day)) %>%
  na.omit()
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why `step_naomit()` is not working here? Thanks!

Comment: Most tidymodels packages like workflows and tune isolate the data being used when making any predictions, to protect against data leakage. This means that the training set and any outcome columns are not available for use at prediction time. If you have done something with the recipe to the outcome, you see errors like this.

Comment: I know that the training and test data are isolated, but still don't get why adding the `step_naomit` has any effect on any column, like `profit_next_day`. As far as I know, `step_naomit` should remove any observation with missing values, so it should use the train data without the missing values and evaluate on the test data also wihtout missing values. And later, extracting the workflow should do the same for any data that matches the columns. What I'm missing here?